# pyspark Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a streaming dataframe `ts` containing `userid` and `timestamp` columns.
I want to define unique row IDs for this dataset grouped by `userid`, and sorted by `timestamp`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
mypartition = Window.partitionBy("userid").orderBy("timestamp")

tss = ts.withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes") \
    .withColumn('row_num', row_number().over(mypartition))

query_rownb  = tss.writeStream.format("memory")\
.outputMode("append") \
.queryName("rownumbers") \
.option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint/path") \
.option('path', "output/path").start()
```

I get this error. What is the way to achieve this?

```
Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75764158/spark-structured-streaming-watermark-being-ignored-old-data-being-output

`The watermark column 'timestamp' is a reserved keyword, changing it to non-reserved name eg. 'ts' fixed the issue.`